# GoogleCharts - annotationの表示を移動させるには

Tags: javascript

GoogleChartsでannotationを各バーの下に表示するにはどうしたらよいでしょうか。
（横長帯グラフの場合）

教えていただけると有難いです。

[image: イメージ図]

コードは以下に

```
<script type="text/javascript">
google.charts.load("current", {packages:["corechart"]});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);


function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['','AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC', { role: 'annotation' } ],
        ['NewYork', 2800, 3900, 3600, ''],
        ['Paris', 1, 2, 2, '']
    ]);

    var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
    var options = {
        annotations: {
            alwaysOutside: true,
        },
        isStacked: 'percent',
        bar: {groupWidth: "85%"},
        hAxis: {
            minValue: 0,
            ticks: [{v:0.1, f:''},{v:0.2, f:''},{v:0.3, f:''},{v:0.4, f:''},{v:0.5, f:''},{v:0.6, f:''},{v:0.7, f:''},{v:0.8, f:''},{v:0.9, f:''}, {v:1, f:''}]
        },
    };


    //formatting of the annotations
    var n = 1;
    var x = 0;
    function getP(data, rowNum){

        x = x + 1;
        var dataval = [];
        var table = [];
        var plus = 0;
        for(var i = 1; i < data.hc[rowNum].length; i++){
            plus += data.getValue(rowNum, i);
            dataval[i] = data.getValue(rowNum, i)
            table[rowNum] = dataval;
        }

        //values into percentages
        var finalp = Math.abs( (table[rowNum][n] / plus) * 100) ;
        var  numb = finalp.toFixed(1);

        //to the next bar
        var divi = data.hc.length;
        if(x % divi == 0){ n = n + 1;}

        return numb + "%";
    }


    view.setColumns([
        0, 1,
        { calc: getP,
          sourceColumn: 1,
          type: "string",
          role: "annotation" },
        2,
        { calc: getP,
          sourceColumn: 2,
          type: "string",
          role: "annotation" },
        3,
        { calc: getP,
          sourceColumn: 3,
          type: "string",
          role: "annotation" },
        4
    ]);


    var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById("chartbox"));
    chart.draw(view, options);
}

</script>
```